# selenium webdriver click event is not working for the option selected from select2 dropdown

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

selenium webdriver click event is not working for the option selected from select2 dropdown.

```
sel_advertiser = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("brand_option"))
for option in sel_advertiser.options:
name = str(option.get_attribute("text"))
if name == advertiser_name:
    print "Found advertiser"
    option.click()
```

In this case if I passed correct advertiser name then it's printing advertiser found. But not selecting the same advertiser from that drop-down. Basically nothing is happening after click.

Can you please let me know what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: sel_advertiser.select_by_visible_text("advertisername") is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the ActionChains class to move to the element a then click. Then the Select2 element would open in Firefox and PhantomJS. It worked without this hack in Chrome but I needed PhantomJS support.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

#Click on the element to open the dropdown
el = driver.find_element_by_id('id_to_element')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(el)
actions.click()
actions.perform()

#Click on the correct item within the dropdown, waiting for it to load
item_to_select = 'Some text in select'

xpath = '//div[@class="select2-result-label" and' +\
    ' text()[contains(.,"%s")]]' % (item_to_select)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elm = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (
            By.XPATH,
            xpath
        )
    ),
    'waiting for %s to be clickable' % (xpath)
)
elm.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

there's no probleme actually.
The webdriver isn't able to refresh the dropdown.

the best way you can see that your dropdown's option is selected is to write something like

```
 option.submit();
```

not a `refresh()`, but a `submit()`.

PS : I had the same problem and i needed to send the form to refresh the dropdown and all the checkboxes too.

Comment: Thanks. If I tried this I am getting "InvalidElementStateException: Message: u'Element was not in a form, so could not submit.'" error.